# Equivalent of dynamic type "automatically adjusts font" setting for UIButton in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, interface-builder

A UILabel has a `Dynamic Type: Automatically Adjusts Font` check-box in the Attributes Inspector in Interface Builder.

Is there an equivalent in Interface Builder for automatically adjusting the font size of a UIButton, or does this have to be handled in code?

I'm using Xcode 9.0 beta 6, targeting iOS 11.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apparently there isn't, but it's not very hard to fix. You can make an extension on `UIButton` with an `@IBInspectable` property:

```
extension UIButton {

    @IBInspectable
    var adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory: Bool {
        set {
            self.titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = newValue
        }
        get {
            return self.titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory ?? false
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can simply turn it on for every UIButton (or any of its subclasses).

[image: Interface Builder]

Comment: Why this isn't part of the SDK by default is beyond me

Comment: this does not work now.

Answer (score 2):

Well there seems to be a way to do it in the Interface Builder only. I use Xcode version 11.5.

**1.** First set as usual a dynamic font type:

[image: Dynamic Font for UIButton]

I choose `Subhead` because according to this [link](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/) it will be 15 pt height which was the font size I had previously set for the button.

**2.** Instead of setting the `titleLabel.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory` in code, you can set it in the "User Defined Runtime Attributes" section in Xcode.

[image: User Defined Runtime Attributes for UIButton]

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution directly on IB without having so much pain of `extension` on button and all that.

In Interface Builder

1. Set `Button Type` from `System` to `Custom`
2. Set as usual `Font` to `Text Style`.

Optional

3. You can set auto layout constrains on `.leading` & `.trailing` so that when Large accessibility text is set, button should not be out of visible area.