# How to scale the fonts in a Button

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton

I'm trying to complete my first app in Swift and I met with the problem.
I have some buttons with the tittles and background image. Running the simulation on different devices makes them scale, so the tittles goes out of buttons frame.
There is no "Dynamic Type Automatically Adjust Font" checkbox in my Xcode attributes inspector so I made the custom UIButton class and made the inspectable var

```
@IBInspectable var adjustFontSize : Bool {
    set { titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = newValue } 
    get { return titleLabel!.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory  }
```

but this does't helps and I got "Automatically adjusts font requires using a dynamic type text style" warning

So how can I make my button title scale to fit the Button frame when the button changes size and proportions on different devices?

Comment: The question seems very simple but believe me I searched all the resources and found no working solutions. Please provide me with it please

Comment: @matt It's been asked before but never accurately answered. To date I've not known anyone to have a way to do this without resorting to creating a UIView with a label in it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46139099/equivalent-of-dynamic-type-automatically-adjusts-font-setting-for-uibutton-in

Comment: @DimitryTheBlack Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: `UIButton` doesn't seem to layout properly after a content size category change. If I change the font from super small to super large the button's frame does not change and the content gets clipped. To get around that I used a custom button that has a label manually inserted and this seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
 btn.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
 btn.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
 btn.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Answer (score -2):

Try these

```
button.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 1
button.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
button.titleLabel!.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
```

but for them to work, you will have to set button width constraint either in storyboard or programatically.

This will then make the title size change based on the width of the button.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to make this adjustment, but it does not help when the buttons are scaling horizontaly. The tittle goes out of upper and bottom edge of the button. And there is no "scaleToFitHeight" in Swift

Comment: Are you trying to load the title in 2 lines as this is working fine for me, and I feel this should work as it will size the text based on the width. Or the button height would be too small compared to the width that you are setting so the title is bigger than the height.

Comment: I have just several symbols on a button so there is no need in 2 lines(