# Dynamicaly scale the fonts in UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Just renovating my previous question
[How to scale the fonts in a Button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46282641/6135493)
still have no answer
The problem description - I have some UIButtons created from the main.storyboard interface. The buttons have some tittles. As I use the constrains the button size increases as I change the device screen size. At the same time the tittles font remains the same so I have large buttons with very small tittles. When I use the devices with the small screen as iPhone4 the tittles go out of the button edges.
I tried

```
@IBAction func touchDigit(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
        sender.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        sender.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

I made the class for the buttons with the inspectable var

```
@IBInspectable var adjustFontSize : Bool {
set { titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = newValue }
get { return titleLabel!.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory  }
   }
```

that have no effect.
UILabel have Automatically Adjust Fonts checkbox. UIButton have not.
I'm sure that everyone had such a problem and the solution seems to be simple. Please help to find it!

Comment: Are you trying to get the title label to wrap onto multiple lines *and* to adjust the font size?

Comment: Its just one symbol on a button. As it have font size 25 it looks fine on iPhone7 and pathetic on 12"iPad

Comment: hmmm... One symbol? Which symbol? Which font?

Comment: You can set the button font based on the size class in IB. Click the + next to Font and set a bigger font for bigger size classes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
sender.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
```

Comment: I have just one symbol on a button so I'm sure that the linebreak is not the case